# Angular expression send by id

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

On Select/Option `onchange()` event it should write the value of the JSON file as an angular expression to `test ID div`.

However it writes like it's just a string: `{{names[1].thnev}}`
(And if I put this manually into the `ID div`, it works.)

Can you help me what did I miss? (In the last 4 hours...)
Thank you.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">      
    <select id="thaz" name="thaz" class="selectbox" onchange="onChange(this.value)">
        <option ng-repeat="x in names" value="{{x.id}}">{{x.id}} - {{x.thnev}}</option>
    </select>

    <div id="list"></div>

</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("al_list_th.php")
        .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.records;});
    });

    function onChange(value) {
        document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = "{{names[" + value + "].thnev}}";   
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the built-ins that AngularJS has available to simplify the problem.

In this case, we can use `ngModel` to bind the value of the `select` into a variable that we can use in our template. Let's call this variable `selectVal`.

Then, we can write `{{names[selectVal].thnev}}` directly inside of the `div` that we want this output to live in.

I've put together this example to show the changes:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.selectVal = "default";
  $scope.names = [{id: 0, thnev: 5}, {id: 1, thnev: 6} ];

  //$http.get("al_list_th.php")
    //.then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.records;});
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
     
    <select id="thaz" name="thaz" class="selectbox" ng-model="selectVal">
        <option value="default">None</option>
        <option ng-repeat="x in names" value="{{x.id}}">{{x.id}} - {{x.thnev}}</option>
    </select>

    <div id="list">
     {{names[selectVal].thnev}}
    </div>

</div>
```

**Note:** In my code I added an extra `option` so that there would be a default as opposed to a blank initial dropdown. You don't have to do this -- the code will work the same without it.

Comment: PS: Since it runs SQL PHP query and the ID starts with 1 (not like 0 in arrays), with a little modification works perfectly. {{names[selectVal-1].thnev}}